# Attribute error when trying to construct GDS graph from a data frame

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-data-science

I am gettin an attribute error when using graphdatascience to construct a graph from a simple dataframe. I am unsure what is missing from my code to make it work

```
import pandas as pd
import neo4j
from graphdatascience import GraphDataScience

gds = GraphDataScience("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=None)

nodes = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        "nodeId": [0, 1, 2, 3],
        "labels":  ["A", "B", "C", "A"],
        "prop1": [42, 1337, 8, 0],
        "otherProperty": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
    }
)

relationships = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        "sourceNodeId": [0, 1, 2, 3],
        "targetNodeId": [1, 2, 3, 0],
        "relationshipType": ["REL", "REL", "REL", "REL"],
        "weight": [0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 42.0]
    }
)

G = gds.alpha.graph.construct(
    "my-graph",      # Graph name
    nodes,           # One or more dataframes containing node data
    relationships    # One or more dataframes containing relationship data
)


UnableToConnectError: Couldn't connect to localhost:7687 (resolved to ('[::1]:7687', '127.0.0.1:7687')):
Failed to establish connection to ResolvedIPv6Address(('::1', 7687, 0, 0)) (reason [Errno 61] Connection refused)
Failed to establish connection to ResolvedIPv4Address(('127.0.0.1', 7687)) (reason [Errno 61] Connection refused)
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware of copying code because there is a note that says "Use your neo4j credentials according to your setup"

> https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/python-client/getting-started/#_import_and_setup

```
from graphdatascience import GraphDataScience

**# Use Neo4j URI and credentials according to your setup**
gds = GraphDataScience("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "my-awesome-psw"))

print(gds.version())

Result:
2.1.4
```

The error you are getting is because it is unable to connection to your local database without authentication (auth=None)